# Django Bootstrap + Modal + DatePicker

Tags: jquery, python, django

I can't seem to get the date-picker working. I'm not sure what im doing wrong. Im pretty sure Im passing the right name but Im not sure if I have it all setup right?

HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load static %}{% load staticfiles i18n %}
{% block title %}Jobs{% endblock %}


{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "datepicker/css/datepicker.css" %}"/>
    <script src="{% static "datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" %}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#job_pickup_date, #filter_pickup_date, #filter_dropoff_date').datepicker({
                'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal_new">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">New Job</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <form method="post" action="">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            {% bootstrap_field form_job.pickup_date class="datepicker" %}
                            {% bootstrap_field form_job.pickup_city %}
                            {% bootstrap_field form_job.pickup_state %}
```

Base HTML:

```
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/app.css" %}"/>
<script src="{% static "js/app.js" %}"></script>


<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

{% block css %}
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- Your stuff: Third-party css libraries go here -->
{% bootstrap_css %}
<link href="http://v4-alpha.if %.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/narrow-jumbotron.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- This file store project specific CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

{% endblock %}

{% block angular %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And bottom of base.html:

```
    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    {% block javascript %}
      <!-- Latest JQuery -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

      <!-- Your stuff: Third-party javascript libraries go here -->

      <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
      <!-- place project specific Javascript in this file -->
      <script src="{% static 'js/project.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock javascript %}
    {% block sripts %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the console say anything?

Comment: What does it do at the minute? was does "not working" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: console doesn't say anything. It all 'appears' to be working but when I click on it, nothing pops up.

Comment: If you go to the network tab of the developer options are any of the requests unsuccessful?

Comment: http://imgur.com/TO8ODBm

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is because modals start as hidden and thus don't apply many libraries' functionality if you call it before the modal is visible. Hook your modal with an onshown event and call datepicker() then:

```
$(".modal").on("shown", function()
{ 
    $('#job_pickup_date, #filter_pickup_date, #filter_dropoff_date').datepicker(
    {
        'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Comment: That didn't work either. And I think when I put {% bootstrap_field job_form.pickup_date %} that it's instantiating it instead of leaving it hidden

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this "bootstrap_field" template tag that you're using (I'm using Crispy Forms currently), but after Crispy Forms renders the form's input element, all of my Datepicker directives are set in that input element:

```
input class="dateinput form-control" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date-start-date="0d" data-date-today-highlight="true" data-provide="datepicker" id="id_target_completion_date" name="target_completion_date" type="text">
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more insight? What do you mean all the directives are set in that input element?

Comment: Just now seeing this, but..  What I mean is, the final HTML code for the date input field had those attribute - "data-*".  So however your date input form field is rendered (in your case: {% bootstrap_field form_job.pickup_date class="datepicker" %}), make sure it ends up with the "data-*" attributes mentioned in my answer.